# Concatenate two strings where first string has a space in the end Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to concatenate two strings using:

```
str=strcat('Hello World ',char(hi));
```

where `hi` is a `1x1 cell` which has the string `'hi'`.

> But `str` appears like this `Hello Worldhi`.

Why am i missing a '' after `Hello World`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in [`strcat`'s documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

> For character array inputs, `strcat` removes trailing ASCII white-space
>       characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and
>       form-feed. To preserve trailing spaces when concatenating character
>       arrays, use horizontal array concatenation, `[s1, s2, ..., sN]`.
>
> For cell array inputs, `strcat` does not remove trailing white space.

So: either use cell strings (will produce a cell containing a string)

```
hi = {'hi'};
str = strcat({'Hello World '},hi)
```

or plain, bracket-based concatenation (will produce a string):

```
str = ['Hello World ',char(hi)]
```

Comment: or use `sprintf ( '%s%s', str1, str2 )` which is very powerful and a lot faster! :)  (And yes a little bit harder to read....)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure why this is happening appart from what's mentioned in the previous answer about the documentation, but the following code should fix your problem.

```
%create two cells with the strings you wish to concatenate 
A = cell({'Hello World '});
B = cell({'hi'});

%concatenate the strings to form a single cell with the full string you
%want. and then optionally convert it to char in order to have the string
%directly as a variable.
str = char(strcat(A,B));
```